# How do I combine 個人/個人的 and 未熟な?

Tags: usage, na-adjectives

> あくまで私の意見です
>
> あくまで私個人の見解です
>
> あくまで私の個人的な意見ですが

All of these seem idiomatic. But when I want to add another word 未熟な into the mix, none of these seem right or widely accepted:

> あくまで私個人の未熟な意見です
>
> あくまで私未熟で個人的な意見です
>
> あくまで私個人的で未熟な意見です
>
> あくまで私未熟な個人の意見です

Comment: With grammar aside, some group of people may think of you as an uneducated person by calling yourself 未熟. They prefer something like 至らない.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

個人的 or 未熟 cannot follow directly a (pro)noun while 個人 can. I don't have a good explanation for this, but similar things can be seen in the following:

- 彼{特有, 固有}の *particular to him* is fine while 彼特殊な is not possible.
- 彼一流の *his superb* is fine while 彼二流の is not possible.

So grammatically,

> 1. あくまで私個人の未熟な意見です
> 2. あくまで私**の**未熟で個人的な意見です
> 3. あくまで私**の**個人的で未熟な意見です
> 4. あくまで私**の**未熟な個人の意見です

are possible. One thing is that 未熟な意見 is not entirely idiomatic (an opinion can get mature?), which makes all these give a slightly odd impression. Still 1 should be totally fine, and 2/3 mean roughly the same. 4 sounds more odd because 未熟な個人 pops out and looks like meaning *opinion of mine as a premature individual* and also 私の個人の意見です is not very idiomatic.